# kafka-node group vs consumer vs topic

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am working on kafka-node lately. I have a few doubts:

Here is the scenario: I have say 10 topics, each receiving data and the volumes are high, each message is around 300KB and 5 messages a sec.

Now I want to create a high-level consumer/consumers so as read the data efficiently.

I tried created one highlevel consumer on all the 10 topics with one group id. It worked fine with small volumes, but behaving weird when the volumes increases.

So, I am planning to do the following:

```
1. Create 10 consumers, one for each topic all having different group id.
2. Create 10 consumers with same group id, one for each topic
```

I would like to understand the significance of group id. How the behavior would be in aforementioned cases.

Also do we have max size kafka can handle?

Comment: What's the number of partitions per topic?

Comment: Using the default partitions, guess should be on

Comment: Right, so you have one partition per topic, for a total of 10 topics. With 10 consumers belonging to different groups each consumer consumes from the single partition of subscribed topic (one partition per consumer). If you put all consumers in the same group (and have each subscribe to all 10 topics) then the 10 partitions will be assigned to the 10 consumers (assuming you are not manually assigning partitions). So you'll still have one partition per consumer. I don't see why you should see a different outcome from these two cases, unless one of my assumptions above is not correct.

Comment: Wanted to understand how will be the structure of the two scenarios look like in zookeeper